# How to access Samba shares in Lubuntu 12.10

Tags: lubuntu, samba, pcmanfm, workgroup

Lubuntu uses PCmanFM as it's default file manager. I want to access my samba share with PCmanFM to upload and download files. I've already installed the "samba" and "cifs-utils" packages and thier dependancies. Installing them seems to allow me to see the windows network which I can open and see my workgroup, but I cannot open the workgroup. It looks like nothing happens when I click on it, but after a minute or two I start to get "Failed to retrieve share list from server" and "The specified location is not mounted" messages. I should have to authenticate a username and password before I can access the samba share, but no dialog comes up asking for any info.

How can I get PCmanFM to access my shared files?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should work:

```
smb://<machine_name/ip>/filepath/filename
```

in the PCmanFM address bar.
e.g:

```
smb://192.168.1.111/some_folder/sub_folder/file.pdf
```

**Courtesy:** https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/PCManFM#Browse_Windows_PCs_with_Samba

**Update:**

If you want to connect as a particular user, use

```
smb://username@smb_server/some_folder
```

Under Lubuntu 14.10, this brought up a password dialog and then connected with the expected ownership and privileges.

Courtesy: Comment by [Randall Cook](https://askubuntu.com/users/61827/randall-cook)

FYI, PCmanFM mounts samba shared devices in `/run/user/userid/gvfs` (`id -u` can help to find user id)
so after mounting Samba shares using PCmanFM, we can also access files/directories using console

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Saji, I tried in Raspbian with LXDE and works just fine.

Comment: If you want to go directly to the folder under your user ID, you can use backticks in the command like so: `cd /run/user/\`id -u\`/gvfs` If you have only one SMB share mounted using `PCmanFM` you can do really nice one-liners like this `cd /run/user/\`id -u\`/gvfs/\`ls /run/user/\\`id -u\\`/gvfs\``

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Lubuntu 17.10 and `smbclient -L WINDOWS-PC` always returns this error:

```
 protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE
```

By adding the following line in global settings of `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, it solves my issue for smbclient and pcmanfm:

```
[global]
    client max protocol = smb3
```