# Transfer files between Ubuntu 15.04 and Windows 7 via Ethernet

Tags: networking, lubuntu, ethernet

I'm trying to get my backup files in a shared folder in my Win7 desktop back to my laptop running Lubuntu 15.04.

The two pc's are connected directly via Ethernet, now I need to access the shared folder but I can't figure out how. I've read a dozen tutorials but no one works. Thanks for any help!

---

EDIT: This is the window that opens after clicking on Go > Connect to server: ...I need 10 rep to post it here, please see https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqNTv.jpg

Comment: Following [these instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/176471/how-to-share-files-between-windows-and-linux/) I was able to access the shared folder over wi-fi, but I need the Ethernet's speed to transfer the bulk of the backup.  Running the same `sudo mount.cifs //WINDOWS-PC/...` command over the Ethernet I get `mount error: could not resolve address for WINDOWS-PC: Unknown error`.  Changing `WINDOWS-PC` with the IP adress I get asked for the shared folder password and then it says `mount error(101): Network is unreachable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to configure IP address for both Ubuntu and Windows 7. (http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/). Also change Ubuntu IP address ([How to set static IP address?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338442/how-to-set-static-ip-address))

Windows 7 IP Configurations

```
IP Address : 192.168.2.2
Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.0
Default gateway : 192.168.2.1
```

Ubuntu IP Configurations

```
IP Address : 192.168.2.3
Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.0
Default gateway : 192.168.2.1
```

You can use some other IP addresses. For example I used above ones. Then share the folder from Windows (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/share-files-with-someone#1TC=windows-7)

Then go to Nautilus in Ubuntu. Click on `Connect to Server` on left pane. Type `smb://192.168.2.2`. Click connect. Then enter username and password. All the shares will appear. Copy and paste them on your Ubuntu computer using Nautilus. If you are using Dolphin please refere - http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE_113/opensuse-kdeuser/cha.network.html#sec.network.ad.data

Click on  add network folder.

[image]

Select Microsoft Windows Network drive.

[image]

Provide windows computer ip. Click Save & Connect

[image]

Provide the password for windows computer. (with domain name) If you dont have domain name just provide normal username and password. If it doesn't work try `WORKGROUP\<username>`
[image]

If you are using PacMANFM, in address bar type `smb://192.168.1.2/`

Comment: I'm on Lubuntu so I'm using PCManFM. I went to Go > Connect to server. Now it asks for type, host, port, path and login. What do I need to do? Sorry, I'm a complete newbie to Linux.

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I'm sorry my fault. I thought you have nautilus. http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE_113/opensuse-kdeuser/cha.network.html#sec.network.ad.data might help you

Comment: I've added a link to the screenshot in the question.

Comment: I updated answer for dolpin

Comment: @ArchStanton What are the types avalaible in go to server dialog box. Can you use dolphin? Are you familiar with network setup?

Comment: The choice is between FTP, SSH and WebDAV. I know something about networks but I'm not really familiar..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26887/discussion-between-dedunumax-and-arch-stanton).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/249678/how-to-access-samba-shares-in-lubuntu-12-10

Answer (score 2):

Try NitroShare ! Which will support Ubuntu as well as Windows

To Install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/nitroshare-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nitroshare
```

For details [click here](http://nitroshare.net)

Comment: I'd prefer to use a more native way, but if nothing else works I'll give it a shot. Thanks :-)

Comment: @ArchStanton: and if it works, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**